# Is this Molex flexible antennas feeding method consider insert or probe feed? what is the most accurate way to simulate it in HFSS?

Tags: antenna, simulation, electromagnetism

I want to do some data augmentation to the radiation pattern of an off-the-shelf flexible antenna (in terms of bending, material, size...etc). To get started I tried my best to recreate the trace pattern of this flexible antenna from Molex in HFSS.

[image]

The trace size and trace pattern of the antenna is a rather easy parts to recreate in HFSS. But I don't know what to do with the feeding in HFSS. The above antenna is listed as a patch antenna, and I don't know whether this patch antenna is considered an insert feed (typically using a lump port in HFSS), or a probe feed(typically using a wave port).

Here the feeding of the actual antenna looks like a coax line that is connected to a pad on the antenna using a blob of solder. And the antenna patch- dielectric- ground is NOT "sandwiched" like the ones mentioned in the textbook, rather the antenna patch and the ground is on the same plane and both have a pad to connect to the coax. So does that consider more of a probe feed or an insert feed? What will be the best way to make an accurate simulation for these kinds of antenna?

Thanks

Comment: The term “patch” is ambiguous here. In this case it just means the antenna is flat, semi-flexible, and designed to be adhered to a nonconductive surface. It’s not the sandwich design referred to as a patch antenna. Excite it with an insert feed between the coax center conductor and shield connections.